# vim/sed remove white spaces column wise

Tags: vim, sed

i have a CSV file with 3 columns. It looks like this

```
col1,col2,col3
123,abc , 2015-01-01
246,def , 2015-02-02
```

How can i remove the white space in col3 only using vim/sed?

expected output:

```
col1,col2,col3
123,abc ,2015-01-01
246,def ,2015-02-02
```

Comment: but i only want to change col3 and col2 may have commas in weird places as its text

Answer (score 0):

#### vim

In vim, this command works for your example:

```
%s/,[^,]*$/\=substitute(submatch(0)," ","","g")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat foobar.csv
col1,col2,col3
123,abc , 2015-01-01
246,def , 2015-02-02

$ sed 's/\(.*\),\(.*\),\(\s*\)\(.*\)/\1,\2,\4/' foobar.csv
col1,col2,col3
123,abc ,2015-01-01
246,def ,2015-02-02
```

Remember the `-i` flag if you want to edit the file in place.